# Cannot add clustering effect to google map code

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am a rookie, and I have been struggling a lot to add clustering effect to my google map javaScript, even though I added the command:

```
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
{imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
```

What I want is like this: [desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpQkw.png), but instead all I got with my code is: [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoaRf.png).

```js
var styles = [
  [{
    url: '../images/people35.png',
    height: 35,
    width: 35,
    anchor: [16, 0],
    textColor: '#ff00ff',
    textSize: 10
  }, {
    url: '../images/people45.png',
    height: 45,
    width: 45,
    anchor: [24, 0],
    textColor: '#ff0000',
    textSize: 11
  }, {
    url: '../images/people55.png',
    height: 55,
    width: 55,
    anchor: [32, 0],
    textColor: '#ffffff',
    textSize: 12
  }],
  [{
    url: '../images/conv30.png',
    height: 27,
    width: 30,
    anchor: [3, 0],
    textColor: '#ff00ff',
    textSize: 10
  }, {
    url: '../images/conv40.png',
    height: 36,
    width: 40,
    anchor: [6, 0],
    textColor: '#ff0000',
    textSize: 11
  }, {
    url: '../images/conv50.png',
    width: 50,
    height: 45,
    anchor: [8, 0],
    textSize: 12
  }],
  [{
    url: '../images/heart30.png',
    height: 26,
    width: 30,
    anchor: [4, 0],
    textColor: '#ff00ff',
    textSize: 10
  }, {
    url: '../images/heart40.png',
    height: 35,
    width: 40,
    anchor: [8, 0],
    textColor: '#ff0000',
    textSize: 11
  }, {
    url: '../images/heart50.png',
    width: 50,
    height: 44,
    anchor: [12, 0],
    textSize: 12
  }],
  [{
    url: '../images/pin.png',
    height: 48,
    width: 30,
    anchor: [-18, 0],
    textColor: '#ffffff',
    textSize: 10,
    iconAnchor: [15, 48]
  }]
];
var markerClusterer = null;
var map = null;


var dataitem = {
  "property": [{
      "property_id": 1,
      "property_title": "11111111111",
      "longitude": -1.561593,
      "latitude": 12.238333
    },
    {
      "property_id": 2,
      "property_title": "2222222222",
      "longitude": 42.590275,
      "latitude": 11.825138
    },
    {
      "property_id": 3,
      "property_title": "3333333333",
      "longitude": 46.869107,
      "latitude": -18.766947
    },
    {
      "property_id": 4,
      "property_title": "4444444444",
      "longitude": 29.873888,
      "latitude": -1.940278
    },
    {
      "property_id": 5,
      "property_title": "5555555555",
      "longitude": 6.613081,
      "latitude": 0.18636
    },
  ]
};


var title = "Title";
var latitude = null;
var longitude = null;
var latitudetest = null;
var longitudetest = null;
var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.213024, 6.111170),
  zoom: 18,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
};

var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';





function refreshMap() {
  if (markerClusterer) {
    markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
  }


  var markers = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {

    var dataProperty = dataitem.property[i];
    latitudetest = dataProperty.latitude;
    longitudetest = dataProperty.longitude;
    var data = dataProperty.property_title;
    var mylatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitudetest, longitudetest);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: mylatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Title',
      label: labels[i % labels.length]

    });
    markers.push(marker);



    (function(marker, data) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
        infoWindow.setContent(data);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    })




  }

  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
  });


}

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 1,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(46, 36),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  });
  var refresh = document.getElementById('refresh');
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(refresh, 'click', refreshMap);
  var clear = document.getElementById('clear');
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(clear, 'click', clearClusters);
  refreshMap();
}

function clearClusters(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map-container {
  padding: 6px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ccc #ccc #999 #ccc;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5) 0 2px 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.1) 0 2px 5px;
  width: 800px;
}

#map {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
}

#actions {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#inline-actions {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.item {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#map_canvas {
  height: 360px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>our projects</title>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCA8R_oBOCd_777EmACopMyl5iFiV3o2UM"></script>
  <script src="data.json"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
  <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <h3>QSP Projects in the World, zoom out to view details</h3>
  <div id="map-container">
    <div id="map"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="inline-actions">
    <span>Max zoom level:
        <select id="zoom">
          <option value="-1">Default</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
          <option value="13">13</option>
          <option value="14">14</option>
        </select>

      </span>
    <span class="item">Cluster size:
        <select id="size">
          <option value="-1">Default</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
          <option value="70">70</option>
          <option value="80">80</option>
        </select>
      </span>
    <span class="item">Cluster style:
        <select id="style">
          <option value="-1">Default</option>
          <option value="0">People</option>
          <option value="1">Conversation</option>
          <option value="2">Heart</option>
          <option value="3">Pin</option>
       </select>
       <input id="refresh" type="button" value="Refresh Map" class="item"/>
       <a href="#" id="clear">Clear</a>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Can someone please have a look at my code here and tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running your projects, make sure to check the console for any errors. This can help you debug your programs. You can access the console by opening up the [developer tools of your browser](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/77337) and choosing the console tab.

When I ran your JSFiddle and looked at the console, these are the errors that were produced:

[image: JSFiddle console errors]

I got rid of the `Failed to load resource` errors by removing the following lines from your HTML:

```
<script src="data.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
```

These two lines are trying to load resources that don't exist. That's why the server 'responded with a status of 404'.

The last error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined` was produced because you try to access the `latitude` property of a data item that does not exist in your current project. You created a loop that repeats 1000 times but your data (`dataitem.property`) only has 5 items.

So when the counter variable, `i`, gets to 5 and your code tries to access the array item at this position (`dataitem.property[i];`) the value `undefined` is returned and this is what the variable `dataProperty` is set to. This breaks all your subsequent code as it tries to access properties of `undefined` that do not exist (such as `dataProperty.latitude;`).

So changing

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataitem.property.length; ++i) {
```

makes your code loop the necessary amount of times to go over all the data in `dataitem.property`. Making that change should fix your code.